# "DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d" while using OpenAPI generator

Tags: python, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenAPI Swagger 'python-flask' generator to generate server code. My YAML contains:

```
  properties:
    value:
      type: string
      format: decimal
      pattern: '^\d+([.]\d+)?$'
```

Generating with:

```
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli  \
    generate \
    -i "$OPEN_API_YAML" \
    -g python-flask  \
    -o gen/python-flask \
    --additional-properties=packageName=my_server
```

Generated python code produces deprecation warnings, like this:

```
DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
raise ValueError("Invalid value for `value`, must be a follow pattern or equal to `/^\d+([.]\d+)?$/`")  # noqa: E501
```

I have a tons of such attributes and get a tons of such warnings :(

**My question: how can I prevent these warnings from showing up?**

I'm using python 3.6.9

Comment: Have you checked the docs? Normally when something is deprecated, the docs suggest an alternative.

Comment: The docs of python suggest changing string to r".." notation, but I can't change generated code. At least not permanently. The docs of the python-flask generator saying nothing about this problem :(. I can create an issue on openapi-generator-GitHub, but I have a filling, that its something simple, that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pattern: '^\\d+([.]\\d+)?$'
```

i.e. double `\\` .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I can't test it now. Maybe later, will see :) Hope it will help others.